# Recommended way to create AWS SNS topics and SQS queues and subscribing queues to topics

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

We have dozen SNS topics and SQS queues that subscribe to those topics.
We want to automate the process of creating topics and queues and subscribing queues to topics so it is easily set up on different environments.
Is there a recommended approach for this?
Or if someone can steer me in the right direction based on their experiences.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your best approach could possibly be use cloudformation templates.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToSQS.cloudformation.html

The only problem is that you'll easily find yourself going doing a deep rabbit hole so beware